# Doctrine - Query with condition on related entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-sourcing

I have this schema:

```
 Entity        Doctrine-generated        Entity
+++++++++       ++++++++++++++++        +++++++
+Student+ ----- +Student/Events+ ------ +Event+
+++++++++       ++++++++++++++++        +++++++
```

What this says is that a Student can have many events, and is represented with a ManyToMany relationship. The Student is the owning side of the relationship.

Each `Event` is added with an incremental `id` and associated to a `Student`. Of course, the mapping table is generated automatically by doctrine due to the `ManyToMany`.

I'm using `event sourcing` for this, so each `Student` has a `status`, that status is the Student's last event.

Now I would like to fetch all `Students` that have a given status, say, for instance, "IN_REVIEW". Remember that the status is represented by the Student's last event.

¿How can I do this with doctrine in just one trip to the database? More specifically, I would like to do this with a query builder.

PD: I have the following code:

```
  $qb->select('a')
  ->from("DnDRaHApiBundle:Student", "a")
  ->leftJoin("a.status", "s");
```

But can't figure out how to query on the mapping table. I've already thought on fetching all `Events` of a `Student` in reverse id order, then use that to query for a Student, but I don't like that approach, there has to be a better way.

Comment: So you have multiple events & event types for a student & you want to fetch all students that have a certain event type, where that event type is their most recent event? How does the Application entity fit into this?

Comment: @Richard I copy pasted my code without changing it, I'll just edit it now... But in that case, Application == Student

Answer (score 0):

With what i understand, i can propose you this:

```
$qb->select('Distinct a')
  ->from("DnDRaHApiBundle:Application", "a")
  ->leftJoin("a.status", "s")
  ->where('s.name = :name')//change name and put your real attribute
  ->orderBy('s.id','Desc')//the most recent have a the higher id
  ->setParameter('name','APPROVED');
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach, I would get Students that were in a status (event), but currently aren't. For instance, suppose, a Student has this chain of events in his lifecycle: PENDING, IN_REVIEW, ACCEPTED, and I query for all students IN_REVIEW. I would get back an APPROVED Student which is wrong.